# How to alter each slider section length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, uielement

A Slider is divided into number of sections depending on range of slider. 
**For example** if range in slider is 1 so slider is by default divided into two sections, to set slider to '1', i have to move the slider past the mid point which is not good By UX point of view.So i am searching for a way by which i can decrease the default section length, so that slider value can be changed by little slider movement.[image][image]
Above ,

- first image shows a slider with range 1.
- second image shows slider set to 1, by clicking on slider past the mid way.

I am using con template and angular js.

Code segment in php file:-

```
<span class="range-field">
                        <input ng-model="diff.setvalue" type="range" min="0" max="{{diff.maxvalue}}" 
                            value="0" style="display:inline"/>
                    </span>
```

Comment: Without presenting any code this would seem to be a User Interface question, rather than a programming problem, and therefore *may* be appropriate for [ui.se] rather than [SO]. If you've attempted a solution to your problem with which you'd like some help then please take the time to show us your attempts, and explain the failures.

Comment: use dragstart event to detect which way they are sliding it, and how far they slide it, then you can update the slider programmatically if they have dragged it far enough to change the value.